# The most efficient way to iterate over a list of elements. Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops, cpython

I am trying to iterate over a list of elements, however the list can be massive and takes too long to execute. I am using newspaper api. The for loop I constructed is:

```
for article in list_articles:
```

Each article in the list_articles are an object in the format of:

```
<newspaper.article.Article object at 0x1103e1250>
```

I checked that some recommended using xrange or range, however that did not work in my case, giving a type error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

It would be awesome if anyone can point me to the right direction or give me some idea that can efficietly increase iterating over this list.

Comment: Did you try `for x in range(len(list_articles)):`? Odds are, you're getting `TypeError` because you just did `for x in len(list_articles):`

Comment: The bottleneck here isn't how you're iterating, and changing to `xrange` or whatever won't make it faster - quite the opposite, actually. The problem is much more likely to be in what you're doing inside the loop, or in some poorly-designed aspect of your code's overall structure.

Comment: You already have the list, and the method you are using for iterating is the most efficient. Since you say there are a lot of articles, you will need to get rid of the list and the only way to do this is to create a custom iterator which pulls a newspaper article using the api and caches only a few of them to avoid network overhead. This iterator can then provide an article each time it is called in the loop and retrieves some more when it's cache becomes stale or runs out

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking to optimize iterating over a list which is as efficient as it can get with `for x in my_list`.  If you need help optimizing other aspects of your code that can be optimized you would be more likely to get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use built in functions, when possible, such as functions to split strings, join strings, group things, etc...

The there is the  list comprehension or `map` when possible. If you need to construct one list from another by manipulating each element, then this is it.

The thirst best way is the `for item in items` loop.

**ADDED**

One of the things that makes you a Python programmer, a better programmer, takes you to the next level of programming is the second thing I mentioned - list comprehension and map. Many times you iterate a list only to construct something that could be easily done with list comprehension. For example:

```
new_items = []
for item in items:
    if item > 3:
    print(item * 10)
    new_items.append(item * 10)
```

You could do this much better (shorter and faster and more robust) like this:

```
new_items = [item * 10 for item in items if item > 3]
print(items)
```

Now, the printing is a bit different from the first example, but more often than not, it doesn't matter, and even better, and also can be transformed with one line of code to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little benchmark to make the question a little bit more interesting:

```
import timeit
import random

N = 1000000


class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.n = random.randint(0, 1000)

bar = [Foo() for r in xrange(N)]


def f1(lst):
    return [v for v in lst]


def f2(lst):
    return [v for index, v in enumerate(lst)]


def f3(lst):
    return [lst[i] for i in range(len(lst))]

K = 100
print timeit.timeit('f1(bar)', setup='from __main__ import f1, bar', number=K)
print timeit.timeit('f2(bar)', setup='from __main__ import f2, bar', number=K)
print timeit.timeit('f3(bar)', setup='from __main__ import f3, bar', number=K)
```

In my machine gives:

```
5.1150355947
6.89524135475
7.90469366922 
[Finished in 22.1s]
```

Conclusion: Iterating using the idiom `for v in huge_list` is a really good choice, so you should profile to check where the bottleneck is, which is probably in the inner loop (items processing)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13529260)

Comment: Hcorg: I don't know what you're talking about... I think this is proving iterating like the OP is doing is possibly one of the best ways to iterate over a huge list. So, could you please elaborate? Anything wrong with the current benchmark? Cos I don't understand your downvote at all :P

Comment: 1. Before edit this post was not a clear answer - just some benchmark :) 2. I didn't give downvote